# InvalidBasicConstraints: A certificate's basic constraint extension has not been observed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate, x509certificate

I am getting the error `"InvalidBasicConstraints: A certificate's basic constraint extension has not been observed."` This certificate was issued with OpenSSL and will be used as a server-side test certificate for a WCF service (which gives the same error when validating the certificate). I can replicate the error with this code.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\test.cer");

X509Chain chain = X509Chain.Create();
X509ChainPolicy policy = new X509ChainPolicy();
policy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
chain.ChainPolicy = policy;
bool valid = chain.Build(cert);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" -- ", chain.ChainStatus.Select(o => o.Status + ": " + o.StatusInformation)));
Console.WriteLine(valid ? "VALID" : "NOT VALID");
```

Viewing the certificate I can see these basic constraints,

```
Subject Type=End Entity
Path Length Constraint=None
```

**What does this error mean and how can I fix it?**

The most relevent article I found on basic constraints was this one, http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/03/16/using-the-basic-constraints-extension-in-x509-v3-certificates-for-intermediate-cas/ however it only talks about prohibiting a child certificate from signing / creating more child certificates which in my case I'm not trying to do.

Also any references that explain what the above basic constraints mean would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://forums.juniper.net/t5/SSL-VPN/quot-Failed-to-authenticate-client-certificate-quot-after/td-p/89232/page/4

After reading the above thread I see there are two different subject types,

```
Basic Constraints: Subject Type=CA, Length Constraint=None
Basic Constraints: Subject Type=End Entity, Path Length Constraint=None
```

The server-side certificate I'm using is actually the 3rd link in a hiearchy.

A -> B -> C....A issued B which then issued signed C.

Certificate B also has `Subject Type=End Entity` in the basic constraints. I cannot find any documentation which states the different types of basic contraints or their meanings, but based on the difference of the above 2 types, I would say that `End Entity` means it CANNOT issue certificates. It is the end of the chain, as opposed to `Subject Type=CA`.

When .NET is validating the chain it sees that B does not have permission from it's father certificate to issue certificates and throws the error, `A certificate's basic constraint extension has not been observed`.

**Edit:** Further testing with a new certificate that was issued by a self-signed certificate verifies the above theory.

Comment: Your observation makes sense to me too. THX!